# SharePoint 2010 video player with playlist

Tags: web-part, video

Is there a free component to serve as an audio/video player with playlist support in SharePoint 2010? We need to have it get its playlist from a SharePoint list of URLs to media files. We'd drop it as a web part and set the list name property.

Thanks.

Comment: In addition to Gillis suggestion for JWPlayer, you can also try FlowPlayer too.

Comment: Thanks, Larry. I've used FlowPlayer and that's a very good option :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the JWPlayer. It's quite easy to embed this component into a visual webpart.
Here's an example of how to create a playlist with this component. You can generate the XML file from a sharepoint list.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player-setup-wizard?example=206

Comment: Thanks, Sven. I came across this commercial product which wraps JW Player 4.x with some web part code to enable connecting it to a list of videos: http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5747

Comment: Hi, Sven. How do I pull the RSS feed of the SharePoint document library of videos (FLVs)? What's the URL for the feed?

Comment: You can build an HTTPHandler, for instance, to create your RSS based on a SharePoint list. I don't think you can use the OOTB RSS feeds of SharePoint. The JWPlayer expects media RSS (MRSS). The syntax for MRSS is a little bit different. Take a look at the following example: http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/mrss.xml

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is no. As Sven said, you can use something like JWPlayer to do the video piece, but you'd need to come up with your own way to get a SharePoint list to be the record of authority for the playlist. In the past I've used SPServices to grab the data from the list and build the playlist that way, but there's no "canned" solution to handle it all.

There are a couple third party media web parts, but the big issue I had was that all of the web parts I found relied either on WMV files or Silverlight; neither of which is an option if your site needs to be iPad compatible. I wrote a [whitepaper](http://mike-greene.com/2010/11/white-paper-sp2010-enhancements-for-the-ipad/) about a year ago that addresses the issues of iPad compatible embedded video if you're interested.